# Can i run separate ejabberd process for test purpose?

Tags: linux, ejabberd

i created a module that modifies packets and save some data to production database. how to change and test module without affecting clients that already connected to `ejabberd` process.

Can i run separate `ejabberd` process for test purpose that uses modified module?
so when anything were ok i use new module for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to install ejabberd in another machine, a developer machine, not in the production one. But i guess you have only one...

Yes, you can install ejabberd in another path, for example with:

```
./configure --prefix=/tmp/eja1
make install
```

In ejabberd.yml configure that ejabberd to use different port numbers, instead of 5222, use 5322 or whatever...

In ejabberdctl.cfg configure a different erlang node name, instead of ejabberd@localhost, call it ejatest@localhost for example.